# How to align the content of the column to the center vertically? Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello i need to align the content of the column to the center vertically.
This is the image of my form

[image: Bootstrap form]

And code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <label translate="global.field.name" for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <label translate="global.field.code" for="code">Code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <label translate="global.field.translation" for="translation">Translation</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col" >
            <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
            <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </div>
```

How to align the last column to the center vertically?

Comment: it already is since div has no height set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the div you want to align:

```
.vcenter {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;}
```

Comment: question is asking about vertical alignment, not horizontal

Answer (score 1):

You could use flexbox like this..

```
.vcenter {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

<div class="row vcenter">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <label translate="global.field.name" for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <label translate="global.field.code" for="code">Code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <label translate="global.field.translation" for="translation">Translation</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-1" >
            <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/Ak9iMhZAuH

Comment: solved my problem with this answer

Comment: why did you accept the other answer?

Comment: Sorry, Your answer solves my problem